# Read data from Password Keeper application in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, passwords

Is possible to read data( like user name, password etc) from Blackberry default *Password Keeper* application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no API to read from the Password Keeper.